# Loop through directory open every file activate sheet and add new column

Tags: excel, vba

I have made code that needs to do the following:

1. scan directory op.xlsx file  #please review
2. open file activate sheet "Buitendelen" (some files don't have so skip file and go on)
3. if sheet "buitendelen" is activated add new column between C and D
4. save file
5. close file
6. go on to next file

It sometimes does not work or it crashes after some time editing files.

```vb
Sub AllFiles_click()
    '//Change the path to the main folder, accordingly
    Call RecursiveFolders("C:\testlab\testmap")
End Sub

Sub RecursiveFolders(ByVal MyPath As String)

    Dim FileSys As Object
    Dim objFolder As Object
    Dim objSubFolder As Object
    Dim objFile As Object
    Dim wkbOpen As Workbook

    Set FileSys = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set objFolder = FileSys.GetFolder(MyPath)

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    'open every folder and subfolder
    For Each objSubFolder In objFolder.SubFolders

        'search for file in folder and subfolder
        For Each objFile In objSubFolder.Files

            'set open workbook
            Set wkbOpen = Workbooks.Open(filename:=objFile)

            'call passwordfirst code to unlock sheets
            Call passwordfirst

            'activated sheet buitendelen
            wkbOpen.Sheets("Buitendelen").Activate

            'call columnadd code to add column
            Call columnadd

            'close workbook and save
            wkbOpen.Close savechanges:=True
        Next

        'start over again
        Call RecursiveFolders(objSubFolder.Path)

    Next

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub

'code to unlock sheets with password
Sub passwordfirst()
    ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="Freonr410a"
End Sub

'code to add column
Private Sub columnadd()
    Columns("D:D").Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
End Sub
```

Comment: Just an FYI, you should really take your password out of this.

Comment: when it crashes what error do you get? also check the comment on step 1

Comment: Just another FYI `Columns("D:D").Insert' will not insert a column between D and E

Comment: @yuca path is right and erro is fout 1004 method insert classe range failed on [code]Columns("D:D").Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove[/code]@josh eller password is fake

Comment: @eVinx a directory can't have a file extension. It is unclear what you mean in your step 1

Comment: @ yuca its the path of the main folder where all de folders and subfolders are where it loops trough for every file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I saw couple of things regarding your code and question. First off, line:

```
ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="Freonr410a"
```

This line, sometimes might cause some issues because, your first active sheet, after you open particular workbook, might not be the *Buitendelen* worksheet. You are depending on someone (or yourself) to close workbook with this sheet active (tricky thing).

This line:

```
Columns("D:D").Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
```

... might also be a root of some problems if it comes to adding new columns. Image that your first worksheet isn't *Buitendele* worksheet. You can successful unlock unprotected worksheet, but now you are trying to add new column to completely different worksheet. Unacceptable.

I saw also that you are omitting any files (except folders) inside your root folder ("C:\testlab\testmap"). That means, if you have any files inside TestMap folder, they will be left untouched. I don't know if this is desired thing or not.

Here, you can find a solution for your problem (tested on W10/ Excel 2017 32 bit)

```
Sub AllFiles_click()
    Call RecursiveFolders("C:\testlab\testmap")
End Sub

' Go through every folder starting from objFolder
' location recursively and add one column after column D
' inside workbook. If Buitendelen worksheet does not exists,
' go to next workbook.
Sub RecursiveFolders(ByVal MyPath As String)
    Const BuitendelenWsName as String = "Buitendelen"

    Dim FileSys As Object
    Dim objFolder As Object
    Dim objSubFolder As Object
    Dim objFile As Object
    Dim wkbOpen As Workbook
    Dim wshToEdit as Worksheet

    Set FileSys = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set objFolder = FileSys.GetFolder(MyPath)

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    For Each objSubFolder In objFolder.SubFolders
        For Each objFile In objSubFolder.Files
            Set wkbOpen = Workbooks.Open(filename:=objFile)

            If SheetExists(BuitendelenWsName, wkbOpen) Then
                Set wshToEdit = wkbOpen.Worksheets(BuitendelenWsName)

                ' Before any changes, worksheet has to be unprotected.
                wshToEdit.Unprotect Password:="Freonr410a"
                wshToEdit.Columns("D:D").Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
            End if

            wkbOpen.Close savechanges:=True
        Next
        Call RecursiveFolders(objSubFolder.Path)
    Next

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

    set FileSys = nothing
    set objFolder = nothing
    set objSubFolder = nothing
    set objFile = nothing
    set wkbOpen = nothing
    set wshToEdit = nothing
End Sub

Public Function SheetExists(byval sheetToFind As String, byref container as Workbook) As Boolean
    Dim sht as Worksheet

    SheetExists = False
    For Each sht In container.Worksheets
        If sheetToFind = sht.name Then
            SheetExists = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next sht 

    set sht = nothing
End Function
```

Extra notes: Please, work on your naming conventions, AllFiles or RecursiveFolders tells nothing about the body of subroutines.

Variable naming conventions: Be precise, if you are going to use Hungarian notation use it - FileSys should be changed to objFileSys.

Comment: thanks for you cleaner code the only thing there are also files that has not the sheet "Buitendelen" but only the sheet "Bezoekers registratie" is there a option to skip this file and go on to next on i think something like if workbook contains 1sheet skip if 2 do the thing

Comment: There is not built in function which will allow to check if worksheet exists or not. I've updated my answer. If you find my reply useful, please mark my answer as "Answer". Also +1 is much appreciated :)